# How to get referrable URLs when generating docs with doxygen

Tags: doxygen

We are using doxygen for our C project. Now we want to link to the generated docs from other web documents. But unfortunately the doxygen generated URLs are horrible and probably not static (i.e. "structbrp___card_families_a51b75b77126880617d10f473314a802f.html").

Is there a way to get static URLs that are looking not that horrible (i.e. "struct_brp_card_families.html")?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The links are stable and should not really change, they are not intended to be used in other packages, but internal in doxygen. To combine multiple doxygen generated documentation parts one can use the TAG facilities (see the doxygen manual). A possibility is to use SHORT_NAMES: If the SHORT_NAMES tag is set to YES, doxygen will generate much shorter (but less readable)
file names. This can be useful is your file systems doesn't support long names like on DOS, Mac, or CD-ROM.

Comment: It is good to know that the urls are stable. But I am asking myself how the long hex number after the name (a51b75b77126880617d10f473314a802f in my example) is generated. If it is derived from anything but the name the url IS NOT stable. If it is derived from the name I am asking myself why the number is needed?

Comment: It is a md5 sum generated from the name (and not sure of the relative directory name).

Comment: Is there a way to disable this MD5 hash? (I see no reason why I would need them)

Comment: No there is no way to disable these md5 hashes, they are needed for unique cross referencing int the output generated by doxygen. When you generate the web documents with doxygen too you could use the doxygen TAG files.